# Validate files using jquery file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am using jquery file upload as below.

```
dialogElem.find('#upload-image-file-input').fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: true,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
            // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
            // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
            // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            previewMaxWidth: 100,
            previewMaxHeight: 100,
            previewCrop: true
        }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
            var fileCount = data.originalFiles.length;
            if (fileCount > 5) {
                alert("The max number of files is : "+5);
                return false; 
            }
          }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
              //some logic
           }).on('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
              //some logic
           }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
              //some logic
            }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
              //some logic
            })
```

Inside `fileuploadadd` I added some validation logic. If the validation is failed, how can I stop all other events like `fileuploadprogress`,`fileuploadfail` and `fileuploadprocessalways` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have some task like i had few weeks ago - try this:

You can cancel an in-progress upload by aborting the XHR (ajax request) call.
You can bind to the fileuploadadd event of the file input field, submit the request while keeping the jqXHR object and use it for aborting:

```
jqXHR.abort();
```

For example:

```
$(".cloudinary-fileupload").bind('fileuploadadd', function(e, data) {
    jqXHR = data.submit(); // Catching the upload process of every file
});

$('#cancel_button').click(function (e) {
    if (jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.abort();  
        jqXHR = null;
        console.log("Canceled");
    }
    return false;
});
```

The following page includes some more code samples
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/290

just call

```
if (fileCount > 5) { 
jqXHR.abort();  
jqXHR = null; }
```

Comment: Did u try? It works? I have a little bit different image upload, and dont sure about it.

Comment: I will try and let u know..Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

jqXHR.abort() doesnt work for me. But **throw** aborts "add" handling:

```
.bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    if (total_uploads >= maxImagesPerPost){
        throw new Error('Upload maximum reached');
    }
```